# Azure Continuous Integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, integration, pool

I have an MVC 4 application on .NET 4.5.I have my application deployed on Azure cloud.

Up until yesterday I would make changed to my application, then check in to TFS, then my application would automatically get deployed on azure. And everything worked just fine.

But today, after I made some changes, the deployment failed with the following error message:
"The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'."

In the azure configuration management page I have .NET FRAMEWORK VERSION set to 4.5. Furthermore there is no option for 4.0, only 3.5 or 4.5. So this seems strange.

Any ideas what could cause the problem.

p.s. I only made small changes in my Views, I didn't add any libraries or anything like that.

Comment: Have you changed TFS versions or Visual Studio versions recently?

Comment: We experienced the exact same thing today. Failed from one changeset to the next with only very small view changes between changesets.

Comment: I installed an update for Visual Studio. But since the update it was working the next few days, so I don't believe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error in your code/configuration. There was an error in TFS service and many people had the same issue. But now it should be fixed. You can find more information on this page:

[bug tracker](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/c02200a2-0acc-482d-9427-286866f9d1ba)